# Excel Multiplication

Tags: excel, multiplication

```
Fixed Value Dynamic value   Calc Value
100             40             4000
                10  
                30  
                20  
                20  
                40
```

I want to calculate all the `calc value` cell by multiplying `Fixed Value` with `Dynamic Value`.

Please help me to write one formula to calculate all the Calc Value Cell.

Comment: Fixed Value Dynamic value Calc Value
100 40 4000
 10 
 30 
 20 
 20 
 40

Comment: I want to multiply A6 with B1 and result at C1, Similarly B2*A6=C2, B3*A6=C3 upto 10 row. I need easy formula which can done by dragging.

Comment: You should have take efforts to do some research. Check this link on CELL REFERENCING and hope it helps you : http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15.2

Answer (score 0):

```
=$A$2*B2
```

The above works assuming "Fixed Value" is in cell A1.

The dollar sign before "A" means that it will refer to A even when the formula is dragged to the left/right.  The dollar sign before "2" means that it will refer to the second row even when dragged up/down.

You can quickly toggle a reference between fixed and relative for rows/columns by hitting f4 with that reference selected in the formula bar.